# Windows 2008 Server Local Domain

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory

I am looking into creating a local Domain Server to host roaming profiles. I created a domain controller but my clients cannot connect. Clients state they are unable to connect to selected domain.

Any ideas or where I can get started with setting up a local domain? It only about 25 accounts  but I need it to expand to more later down the line. Each profile will have their profile stored on a local server as well.

Where can I get started with this server configuration? I am used to Linux configurations

Comment: If you are migrate to Domain try usefull program **User Profile Wizard** which enable to link local user profile to domain profile. In this case you will not have to migrate user documents and other profiles files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 Setup your DHCP DNS server to point to your newly created AD DNS server. (you did that right?) Release/renew your clients IP.  If you use static IPs ensure DNS is pointed to new AD DNS server.

Answer (score 5):

1. What is a "local" domain? Local to what? As opposed to what other type of domain?
2. The answer is DNS. Configure the clients to use the domain (AD) DNS server(s) for DNS so that they can locate the domain controller for the domain.

Comment: +1 If you have an AD problem, it's **always** DNS. If it isn't, that that just means that you missed the DNS problem.

Comment: It will be local to the network only, no outside connections. I setup an Active Directory but no one was able to connect. The setup process was pretty easy. Any documentation for this would be nice.

Comment: Did you make it a DC after you installed AD Roles and Services aka "dcpromo.exe" which will also require you to create DNS on the server if you do not have an existing one?

Comment: I may have skipped that last step. I did however use dcpromo.exe to set it up but I don't think I actually set up the DC. I will try this and update once I have.